# Quick method read file and skip any lines that don't contain numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a file that is formatted line by line with text and numbers like this:

```
junk
junk
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
junk
.
.
junk
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
junk
```

I would like to read in just the rows that contain the 10 columns of numbers 1:10.

I currently have a solution that works like this:

```
fid = fopen(file)
while 1
    tline = fgetl(file)
    line = sscanf(tline, repmat('%f',1,10));
    if ~isempty(line)
        do stuff
    end
    if feof(fid)
        break
    end
end
```

The problem is the files are 20,000 lines long and I have to do this on 5,000 files - so it takes a long time to run. I'm wondering if there's a quicker solution in MATLAB?

Edit: Out of the 20,000 lines in the text file, 4,000 of them will be formatted with the 10 columns of numbers that I am interested in, the rest ("junk") have a wide variety of text/symbols/other numeric data. They are also not spaced consistently between each files.

Comment: What is "junk"? Do those lines always start with the same text (or a few variants)? If you can link to a real or more representative file, that would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe you can read the first column, and then you'll know which lines you need?

Comment: `textscan` reading multiple lines at once is known to be faster than `fgetl`

Comment: It would be much easier to answer if a more representative data set was provided. Are the intervals between "junk" and "not-junk" data uniform? Do you have enough memory to read a file in completely and parse, rather than parsing line-by-line? No matter how you spin it, parsing 5,000 files with 20,000 lines is going to take a "long" time.

Comment: I guess I was hoping there might be something akin to sed in Matlab that might let me get through this quicker.

Comment: Have you tried `textscan`? You've not said what "junk" is, but you may be able to use it to read the files faster. Also, use the @ symbol and a user name to refer to other user or they may never see your comments.

Comment: @MarkK Why can't you use sed on the files before you feed them to MATLAB?

Comment: @horchler thanks for the tip on user references - I'm new here. text scan won't work because the "junk" is non uniform and varies too wildly. Not formatted in any specific way that would make textscan viable.

Comment: @beaker. I'm trying to automate a workflow using only a Matlab parent script. The reading of the files is one of my bottlenecks. In the end I'll leave it as is I think and just deal with the time it takes. thanks for all the suggestions folks.